# How can I discover all the roles a Perl 6 type does?

Tags: oop, roles, raku, metamodel

With `.does` I can check if a type has the role I already know. I'd like to get the list of roles. Inheritance has `.^mro` but I didn't see anything like that for roles in the meta model stuff.

Along with that, given a "type", how can I tell if it was defined as a class or a role?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```perl6
.^roles
```

```perl6
say Rat.^roles; # ((Rational[Int,Int]) (Real) (Numeric))
```

By default it includes every role, including roles brought in by other roles. To only get the first level use `:!transitive`

```perl6
Rat.^roles(:!transitive); # ((Rational[Int,Int]))
```

Comment: Where did you find that? I didn't see that anywhere in the docs. I guess I should have just tried it.

Comment: @briandfoy I look at every commit of Rakudo. So for example I read the commit where `:transitive` became the default.

Answer (score 9):

There's already a good answer to the first question. About the second one, each meta-object has an `archetypes` method that in turn carries a range of properties of the types represented by that meta-type. This exists because Perl 6 is open to new meta-types (which might be easier to think about as "types of type"); probably the most widely used example of this today is `OO::Monitors`. The archetypes are more focused on what one can do with the type. For example:

```
> role R { }; say "C: {.composable} I: {.inheritable}" given R.HOW.archetypes; 
C: 1 I: 0
> class C { }; say "C: {.composable} I: {.inheritable}" given C.HOW.archetypes; 
C: 0 I: 1
```

The set of available properties can be introspected:

```
> Int.HOW.archetypes.^methods(:local)
(nominal nominalizable inheritable inheritalizable composable 
composalizable generic parametric coercive definite augmentable)
```

For example, "nominal" means "can this serve as a nominal type", and "augmentable" means "is it allowed to augment this kind of type". The things like "inheritalizable" mean "can I inheritalize such a type" - that is, turn it into a type that I *can* inherit from even if I can't inherit from this type. A `role` is not inheritable, but it is inheritalizable, and the inheritalize operation on it will produce the pun of the role. This is what is happening under the hood when writing something like `class C is SomeRole { }`, and means that not only is Perl 6 open to new types of type, but those new types of type can describe how they want to work, if at all, with inheritance and composition.

Being composable with `does` is probably the main defining property of a role, and thus the `composable` property is likely the best one to use when asking "is this a role". It is also possible to look at the type of the meta-object, as suggested in another answer, but there are multiple meta-objects involved in representing roles (the short name role group, a currying of that group with parameters, and an individual role, plus an internal concretization form that supports the composition process).

```
> say (role RRR[::T] { }).HOW.^name
Perl6::Metamodel::ParametricRoleHOW
> say RRR.HOW.^name
Perl6::Metamodel::ParametricRoleGroupHOW
> say RRR[Int].HOW.^name
Perl6::Metamodel::CurriedRoleHOW
```

Thus it's rather more robust to simply check if the thing is composable.

```
> say (role RRR[::T] { }).HOW.archetypes.composable
1
> say RRR.HOW.archetypes.composable
1
> say RRR[Int].HOW.archetypes.composable
1
```

Comment: Which one do you think is the good answer to the first question?

Comment: @briandfoy The one from Brad Gilbert suggesting `.^roles` and pointing out the `:transitive` option.

Comment: The problem is that if it's using NQP roles, that will fail.

Answer (score 6):

> Along with that, given a "type", how can I tell if it was defined as a class or a role?

A class is a type whose meta class is of type `Metamodel::ClassHOW`:

```perl6
sub type-classify(Mu \t) {
    given t.HOW {
        return 'class' when Metamodel::ClassHOW;
        return 'role'  when Metamodel::ParametricRoleGroupHOW;
    }
    return 'other';
}
say type-classify(Int);         # class
say type-classify(Rational);    # role
say type-classify(Bool);        # other
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question,

> given a "type", how can I tell if it was defined as a class or a role?

I haven't found a direct way of doing that. Both classes and roles have [Mu](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Mu) in their hierarchy, so that will not distinguish them. However, only classes get to be recognized by (the curiously named) [`MetaModel::ClassHOW`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Metamodel::ClassHOW#method_can). So we can hack something like this:

```
role Ur { }
role F does Ur { }
class G does F { }
for Ur, F, G -> $class-or-role {
    CATCH {
        default {
            say "not classy";
        }
    }
    $class-or-role.say;
    $class-or-role.^mro.say;
}
```

Which will print:

```
(Ur)
not classy
(F)
not classy
(G)
((G) (Any) (Mu))
```

, since calling `^mro` on a role will raise an exception. That can be turned into a function for printing out which one is a role, and which is not.

Comment: This fails if you pun the role. The role name will show up in the class list.

Comment: @briandfoy if you pun it, it's literally "classed". Plus I'm doing it on the class, not on an object...

Comment: Hence the very specific nature of my second question.

Comment: @briandfoy and the hack in my answer, which actually turns around your first question to answer the second one :-) It's just a hack, anyway.

Comment: Neither of these are suitable for the reason I mentioned.