# Introspecting NQP roles

Tags: oop, mixins, introspection, raku, nqp

From [this question in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402115/how-can-i-discover-all-the-roles-a-perl-6-type-does), I discovered `Type.^roles`, which includes all roles that are composed into a type. It works all over the place, but it fails to print if there are NQP roles somewhere:

```
 say Cursor.^roles# OUTPUT: «No such method 'gist' for invocant of type 'NQPMatchRole'. Did you mean 'ast'?␤  in block <unit> ␤␤»
```

There's no method `gist` or `Str`. However, `^name` seems to work:

```
my @cursor-roles = Cursor.^roles; print $_.^name for @cursor-roles ; # OUTPUT: «NQPMatchRole»
```

Can I assume NQP roles follow the same metamodel as Perl 6, and I can at least use the `^name`? Is there a more general way of printing all roles, including both Perl 6 and NQP roles?

Comment: Can't currently recall where I read about it, but you're right in your observation: NQP toe objects do follow the Metamodel. At least most of it.